# Matplotlib Scatter plot interactivity not working

Tags: python-3.x, scatter-plot, interaction, mousehover

Until this morning I was able to display labels information when hovering the dots on a scatter plot.
Now, if I run the following code it does not display any error but the interactivity is not working and it looks like mplconnect or mlpcursors are completely ignored.
I've tried the same code under windows and Fedora.
Not understanding what's going on.

from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy as npy
from numpy.random import rand

```
    x, y, c, s = rand(4, 100)
    def onpick3(event):
        ind = event.ind
        print('onpick3 scatter:', ind, npy.take(x, ind), npy.take(y, ind))

    fig = figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    col = ax1.scatter(x, y, 100*s, c, picker=True)
    #fig.savefig('pscoll.eps')
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)

show()
```

Or

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.rand(15)
y = np.random.rand(15)
names = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"))
c = np.random.randint(1,5,size=15)

norm = plt.Normalize(1,4)
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlGn

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
sc = plt.scatter(x,y,c=c, s=100, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):

    pos = sc.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = "{}, {}".format(" ".join(list(map(str,ind["ind"]))), 
                           " ".join([names[n] for n in ind["ind"]]))
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor(cmap(norm(c[ind["ind"][0]])))
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)


def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = sc.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

This is not my code, I've copied and pasted it from a website but the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Plotly express solves the problem

import plotly.express as px

```
alpha = data[data['Ticker']==focus].V1
gamma = data[data['Ticker']==focus].V2

fig = px.scatter(data, x='V1', y='V2', color=Colors.Market_Cap, hover_data=["Ticker"] )
fig.add_shape(type="circle",
    xref="x", yref="y",
    x0=int(alpha-3), y0=int(gamma-3), x1=int(alpha+3), y1=int(gamma+3),
    line_color="LightSeaGreen",
)

fig.show()
```